# How to save large data quickly into sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I created Calendar application for android, when i store data(daily plans) for one month in a single instance in my calendar application, the emulator shows not responding alert or it takes about 5 min to store the data. How can I store the data to database as quick.

Answer (score 6):

It is always recommended to use `SQLite Transactions` to store large amount of data. Transactions create single journal file to perform SQLite manipulation, causing the entire process to accomplish quickly.

A simple Transaction would look like:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    /*
     *
     perform sql add/edit/delete here
     *
     */

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
}finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

P.S. If its taking 5 min without transactions, then I hope it should be completed within ±10 seconds when using it.

Also if it does not respond to ui gestures, you are doing database operations in the main thread, move database operations to background thread, preferably by using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Still it takes more time to store and in the catch block I had put               catch(Exception e){
 
} whether I should catch any other exception.

Comment: how much time does it take now? paste your full code. perhaps you are doing something else